# Ping Tomcat from another machine

Tags: tomcat, lan

I have a little issue.

I run Tomcat on my machine and calling it at `localhost:8080` works fine.

Now I want to send a request (e.g. `http://mytomcatserver/myapp`) from another machine on my own LAN.

How can I do this?

I tried to request an `http://myMachineIP:8080/myapp` but it doesn't work. Sorry for my English,  I hope you can help me!

Comment: Should work. Firewall issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, you need two things:

- A DNS server who can tell your other machine what `mytomcatserver` means
- A proxy that connects `mytomcatserver:80` with `localhost:8080`

For the latter, there are pretty simply ones like [netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/) or you can configure [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) for this (use the [proxy module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html)) or you can configure Tomcat to use port 80 instead (but then, you need to run Tomcat as root).

Comment: I am behind a company proxy. I have to configuring port forwarding or not?

Comment: You said both the Tomcat and the other machine were on the same LAN. If so, then the company proxy can be ignored - unless you have configured your browser to send all your requests through the proxy. In that case, ask the admin of the company proxy to forward the requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot Aaron. I got it finally!